# Upgrading InfoPath code 2003 to 2010 (Repeating Section changing event)

Tags: vb.net, infopath

I was able to stop user from removing save repeating section in InfoPath 2003. My code does not work in Infopath 2010. Can anybody find a new way to rewrite the code below?

In InfoPath 2003 within OnBeforeChange of a repeating section, I was able to check DataDOMEvent properties e.Site and e.Source to see who raised that event. For example:

```
 <ParentElement>
  …
 <RepeatingSection IsSave=”false” …>
<Field 1 />
     <Field 2  />
     <Field 3  />
     <Field 4  />
     <Field 5  />
     <Field 6  />
 </RepeatingSection>
 …
 </ParentElement>

 Dim isRowModification As Boolean
 Dim IsSave As Boolean 

 …

 isRowModification = (e.Source Is e.Site)

 If IsSave AndAlso isRowModification Then
     e.ReturnMessage = "You cannot modify or remove this Section."
     e.ReturnStatus = False
 End If
```

In InfoPath 2010 the XmlChangingEventArgs does not have an e.Source Property. When the Changing event for Repeating Section is raise either by a field change or by the Repeating Section itself, e.Site is always point to Repeating Section.  I need a way to know if fields 5 raise the repeating Section changing event.